# Best architecture for describing interaction between spells

Tags: architecture, component-based, roblox, effect-modifier

Interactions serve as retroactions. I'm currently looking the best way to describe interactions between different abilities.

For instance, if we take a fire ability and a water one, a lot of different outcomes are possible. If they have the same strength, expect both of them to vanish and vacuum to form. Now, if we're speaking about a droplet of water against a fire ability, this will obviously be handled differently.

However, I'd like interactions to not only summarise as one ability cancelling each other, but for more complicated behaviours. Here are a few examples of them:

- Fire ability against a plant ability : You'd expect the plant to burn down depending on the fire's **physical properties** (keep in mind this word, it's very important for later)
- Fire ability against an ice ability : You'd expect the ice to melt down depending on the fire's temperature

I initially thought about drawing some huge generalisations regarding different types of abilities interacting with each other, e.g. (Water vs Water, Water vs Fire, Water vs ...), but I realised that it might be a very naive and exhaustive approach on the long run if I were to add a single magic in game and there would already be many!

Next, I considered relying on **physical and chemical properties** of the different abilities that made up my game. Here is a very interesting list of some of physical properties, for instance, on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_property).
My current idea consists in describing the abilities in terms of components and, by example, saying that a fire ability has a `Temperature` component.

However, this approach also seems like an extremely tiresome task! I won't obviously be implementing each of these properties as components, but I feel like there is a lot of work to be done. It's also pretty much a first since I've never heard of a such idea before- perhaps because it is terribly bad. This is why I'd like to know if there's a much better way to handle that, or simply your thoughts/critics regarding it.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Roblox to know its limitations. Perhaps the tiresome task can be automated somehow? Also I don't know if this just for spells or is it also form objects in the world too. However, no, this is not a bad idea per se. The core is to separate material from element. The world of game development is wide and large, broaden your horizons and take a Breath of the Wild. Ah, yes, that is the game that made this popular. They called it a chemistry engine see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyMsF31NdNc. btw, Genshin Impact executes it masterfully. Does it has to be Roblox?

Comment: Amazing! This seems to be what I've been looking for so long. Glad to see that I'm not insane and that it's an actual thing! And yes it has to be happening on Roblox and I was already thinking about this idea of using a component approach, more exactly composition over inheritance so that shouldn't be a huge deal!